# Is it possible to access code of v4.master file?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have some user defined controls in v4.master.

Now some of these controls should be visible depending upon some logic.

Situation:

I have added to link buttons for login and logout on v4.master page. Now only one should be visible at any point of time, either login or logout.

Comment: What exact logic is? It will be easy to respond with some more info...

Comment: @AndrewAdamich, Question edited. Please go through.

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions have something to do with permissions - check out [SPSecurityTrimmed](http://codename-srini.blogspot.ru/2009/04/spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-and.html)
If it's some other logic you could try something like `this.Page.FindControl("ControlID2").FindControl("controlID2").Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Better you create only one user control and in the code behind you check if current user is logged in - you render logout link otherwise login.

Check this link to see how to do [this](http://rburgundy.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/sharepoint-2010-user-login-check/).

Andrew